# firefox OS app,CORS in Firefox os app

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors, firefox-os

I have been developing web-app(not hosted app) in firefox OS .
I want to access the websites xml/JSON data using XMLHttp request. but it gives error as CORS not allowed to access the data . I know about to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in website and enabling CORS may cause security issues.
But is their any alternate way to access the data feed via XMLHttp request?

Answer (score 6):

First change your manifest to have the following fields (the `type` one gets forgotten by people):

```
"type": "privileged", 
"permissions": {
    "systemXHR" : {}
}
```

Second, move all your JavaScript code to a *separate* JS file. Because it's not allowed to have inline  tags in a privileged application.

Third use the mozSystem constructor like raidendev said:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({ mozSystem: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform cross-domain http request from Firefox OS app you need to set permission [systemXHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions#systemXHR) in app's manifest:

```
 "permissions": {
     "systemXHR" : {}
 }
```

and create `XMLHttpRequest` with property [mozSystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#mozSystem) set to `true`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({ mozSystem: true });
```

Also, for any cases where XMLHttpRequest is not applicable, you can use [TCP Socket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCP_Socket_API).

```
var socket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.open('localhost', 80);

socket.ondata = function (event) {
  if (typeof event.data === 'string') {
    console.log('Get a string: ' + event.data);
  } else {
    console.log('Get a Uint8Array');
  }
}
```

Comment: Then provide us some code and logs for identify problem :)

Comment: I already have done that and AJAX is working with the domains where in "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is set on server side.
The website I am working with is PCI-DSS compliant and so I can't change Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as it could open gates to other apps.

Just want to know if there is any way by which I can connect to remote http server and fetch the data as we do in Java skipping CORS. I don't mind if it becomes Synchronous request.

Comment: This is sample code having same concept:-`code`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  
  function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
  }

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = reqListener;
xhr.open("get", "http://www.example.com", true);
xhr.send();
console.log(xhr);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Test</h2>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I've understood, you want to use raw sockets, right? Then look for [TCPSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket) API.

Comment: Can u provide me example?