# Ajax request is not working in Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-os

```
function abc()
{
    console.warn("inside abc");
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    console.warn("value of req" + req);
    if (req) {
        console.warn("inside if req");
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.warn("inside onreadychange");
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    var x = req.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }
        };
        req.open("GET", "upload1.php" + queryString, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}
```

I am calling this function abc on onclick event of save button.

I wanted to upload audio file and for that I am using an Ajax request with javascript.

But here I am getting console msgs before req.onreadystatechange.

My control is not going inside this req.onreadystatechange.function().

Can any one tell me why this is happening and how to solve this issue?

I am not getting any type of error in console.

Comment: Does it work in a browser?

Comment: Where have you created `new XMLHttpRequest()`? Can you post your `getXMLHTTP()`?

Comment: yes i have created this function same like as defined  below and it is returning  xmlhttp  variable.I am working on fire fox os mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work in any browser. I dont think you have `getXMLHTTP()` defined.

You can define it like this:

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp=false;    
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {        
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joo4q90n/

You can replace the querystring though. I have just given some string for testing purpose.

P.S : By `Firefox os`, i assume you meant `Firefox Browser`

Comment: yes i have created this function same like as you have defined and it is returning  xmlhttp  variable.I am working on fire fox os mobile device.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joo4q90n/1/ check out here i am uploading my whole code.and i am creating one application which will capture audio file save it in to SADCARD of fire fox os based device and then i  want to upload this file one server.for that i am using ajax but as i have mentioned i  am stuck at one place.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a packaged Firefox OS app? By default, cross origin requests are not allowed. You have a few options.

1. Change to `type: web` so that your app does not have to adhere to CSP (Content Security Policy).
2. Enable CORS on your API endpoint so that all domains can make cross origin requests to it (this may not be secure enough for your application).
3. Convert your packaged app to `type: privileged` with a `systemXHR` permission. This will allow your app to make cross origin requests but getting your app accepted into the Firefox Marketplace may involve more scrutiny. Explained here: [firefox OS app,CORS in Firefox os app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397511/firefox-os-app-cors-in-firefox-os-app)